# Autocomplete Excel formula with keyboard shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2007

When typing the beginning of a function name in a Excel formula, there is a list of suggestions:

[image]

**How to accept the currently highlighted suggestion, and autocomplete it with a keyboard shortcut, without the mouse?**

I tried with <kbd>TAB</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> but neither works.

Comment: I use "TAB" without problem.

Comment: @Dominique with which Excel version? Maybe it's because I use an old version?

Comment: I'm working with Excel 365.

Comment: Just tried with `Excel 2010++` onwards versions, it needs only `TAB` nothing else. However your answers shows you have assigned it for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Solved, my misake.

(I mapped TAB to an Autohotkey shortcut for some tests the last days.)